# How to start rails server with apache restart?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache

I'm having some issues deploying rails on a CentOS machine.

I think running `rails s -d` will make it persist after the ssh window is closed. However what happens if restarts?

How to make it run `rails s -d` in case apache does restart?

Comment: Are you using Passenger?

Answer (score 1):

You best chance for this would be to run your Rails application as a Apache module, using [Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/). Once Passenger is setup, you have a [nice guide](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_deploying_a_rack_based_ruby_application_including_rails_gt_3) to explain how to deploy your app on it.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using passenger with apache it will solve your problem ..

```
follow
gem install passenger
passenger-install-apache2-module


For Apache installation
    apt-get install apache2-prefork-dev
    apt-get install libapr1-dev
    apt-get install libaprutil1-dev
```

visit

http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html